# Aggregate 3rd dimension of a 3d array for the subscripts of the first dimension

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 Dimensional array Val 4xmx2 dimension. (m can be variable)

```
Val{1} = [1, 280; 2, 281; 3, 282; 4, 283; 5, 285];
Val{2} = [2, 179; 3, 180; 4, 181; 5, 182];
Val{3} = [2, 315; 4, 322; 5, 325];
Val{4} = [1, 95; 3, 97; 4, 99; 5, 101];
```

I have a subscript vector:

```
subs = {1,3,4};
```

What i want to get as output is the average of column 2 in the above 2D Arrays (only 1,3 an 4) such that the 1st columns value is >=2 and <=4.

The output will be:
{282, 318.5, 98}

This can probably be done by using a few loops, but just wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
output = cellfun(@(x)mean(x(:,1)>=2 & x(:,1)<=4,2),Val(cat(1,subs{:})),'UniformOutput',false);
```

If `subs` is a numerical array (not a cell array) instead, i.e. `subs=[1,3,4]`, and if `output` doesn't have to be a cell array, but can be a numerical array instead, i.e. `output = [282,318.5,98]`, then the above simplifies to

```
output = cellfun(@(x)mean(x(x(:,1)>=2 & x(:,1)<=4,2)),Val(subs));
```

`cellfun` applies a function to each element of a cell array, and the indexing makes sure only the good rows are being averaged.

Comment: @ Jonas: Sure, I'll do that. There is another thing i wanted to ask. If Val{3} is an empty vector, the code throws an error: ? ?? Attempted to access x(:,1); index out of bounds because size(x)=[0,0]. Do you know how we can get rid of this error, print NaN rather than throwing an error

Comment: @sdhrm: You can first identify which cells are empty: `emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty,Val);`. Then, you can put `[NaN,NaN]` into these cells: `[Val{emptyCells}] = deal([NaN,NaN]);`